# Backup remote VPS with Rsync

Tags: ssh, vps, rsync

I have a VPS that we will be shutting down soon, so I want to create a full backup of it. I was thinking about rsync, because if I google linux and backup words, I constantly get hit by rsync, so why the hell not. :) However, here comes the kicker.

The backup machine where I want to backup the VPS in not accessible from the internet. So I can't just use what almost everybody suggests to SSH into the VPS, sudo rsync almost everything and as output mark the backup server. I want to run a bash command that does something similar to dd, so if I run rsync on the remote server, I could mark my local folder as output. Also I have to mention, that root ssh login is not allowed, so I can only SSH into the VPS as a user who can actually turn into sudo, but by default it is just a plain user.

I came up with the following rsync command:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /* /backup/machine/folder
```

And I wish to use it somehow like this dd command I've used for cloning but the opposite way:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=4096 | pv | ssh root@<<TargetServer-IP>> ”dd of=/dev/sda bs=4096”
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love to post questions here because about 50% of them is being answered by myself. I usually take a few hours to decide to upload the question here, and after that a few mutes later, I get my answer. :) Here is the command:

```
rsync --dry-run root@omd.myserver.hu:/ -aAXvh --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /backup/backup/servers/omd
```

OFC exclude the --dry-run from the command if you want to execute it. Also, you have to add your SSH public key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file to make this work.